# Arithmetic operation resulted in an overflow

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis-7, overflow

The application is working well in Win server 2003 /IIS 6.0 environment.
When I move the code to win server 2008/IIS 7.0 , I am getting below error? Could you advise what is the error cause? Did i missed anything?

```
Server Error in '/' Application.

Arithmetic operation resulted in an overflow. 
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.OverflowException: Arithmetic operation resulted in an overflow.
```

**Stack Trace:**

[OverflowException: Arithmetic operation resulted in an overflow.]
   System.IntPtr.ToInt32() +37
   CoreLab.Common.a.a(Delegate A_0) +1935
   CoreLab.Oracle.ab.a(OracleConnection A_0) +214
   CoreLab.Oracle.OracleConnection.Open() +375
   MonsterWorldwide.iTime.DataAccess.TimecardDA.GetTimecardPageInfoSet(Int32 personId, Int32 pageNumber, Int32 rowsPerPage, Int32& rowsCountTotal) in c:\inetpub\wwwroot\mtitimeproduction\dataaccess\timecardda.cs:28
   MonsterWorldwide.iTime.BusinessLogic.TimecardBL.GetTimecardPageInfoSet(Int32 personId, Int32 pageNumber, Int32 rowsPerPage, Int32& rowsCountTotal) in c:\inetpub\wwwroot\mtitimeproduction\businesslogic\timecardbl.cs:24
   MonsterWorldwide.iTime.WebGUI.WebParts.TimecardList.LoadData() in c:\inetpub\wwwroot\mtitimeproduction\webgui\webparts\timecardlist.ascx.cs:112
   MonsterWorldwide.iTime.WebGUI.WebParts.TimecardList.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in c:\inetpub\wwwroot\mtitimeproduction\webgui\webparts\timecardlist.ascx.cs:52
   System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +132
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +66
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +191
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +191
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +2428

---

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:2.0.50727.4952; ASP.NET Version:2.0.50727.4927

Comment: Can you post the stack trace and the code that is causing the error?

Comment: [OverflowException: Arithmetic operation resulted in an overflow.]
   System.IntPtr.ToInt32() +37
   CoreLab.Common.a.a(Delegate A_0) +1935
   CoreLab.Oracle.ab.a(OracleConnection A_0) +214
   CoreLab.Oracle.OracleConnection.Open() +375
   MonsterWorldwide.iTime.DataAccess.TimecardDA.GetTimecardPageInfoSet(Int32 personId, Int32 pageNumber, Int32 rowsPerPage, Int32& rowsCountTotalc:\inetpub\wwwroot\mtitimeproduction\dataaccess\timecardda.cs:28MonsterWorldwide.iTime.BusinessLogic.TimecardBL.GetTimecardPageInfoSet(Int32 personId, Int32 pageNumber, Int32 rowsPerPage, Int32& rowsCountTotal)

Comment: in c:\inetpub\wwwroot\mtitimeproduction\businesslogic\timecardbl.cs:24
   MonsterWorldwide.iTime.WebGUI.WebParts.TimecardList.LoadData() in c:\inetpub\wwwroot\mtitimeproduction\webgui\webparts\timecardlist.ascx.cs:112
   MonsterWorldwide.iTime.WebGUI.WebParts.TimecardList.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in c:\inetpub\wwwroot\mtitimeproduction\webgui\webparts\timecardlist.ascx.cs:52
   System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +132
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +66
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +191
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +

Comment: 191System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +2428

Comment: --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:2.0.50727.4952; ASP.NET Version:2.0.50727.4927

Comment: @Ravi, please don't use the comments section to post code snippets as they are not properly formatted and are difficult to read. Update your original question instead to include relevant information.

Comment: ok. Thank for the information . I am new this forum.

Answer (score 1):

```
[OverflowException: Arithmetic operation resulted in an overflow.] 
System.IntPtr.ToInt32() +37 
CoreLab.Common.a.a(Delegate A_0) +1935 
CoreLab.Oracle.ab.a(OracleConnection A_0) +214
```

This looks like some poorly written unmanaged interop code which doesn't take into account the CPU type and which blows when run in a x64 bit OS. In a 64-bit OS pointers are 64-bit integers contrary to 32 bit OS.

Maybe you should check the documentation of this `CoreLab.Common` component you are using whether it supports 64-bit systems.

Quote from the documentation of the [IntPtr.ToInt32](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.intptr.toint32.aspx) method:

> OverflowException: On a 64-bit platform, the value of this instance is too large or too small to represent as a 32-bit signed integer.

Comment: Yes. Currently i am using 64 bit OS ..This might be the culprit.

Comment: The culprit is the component you are using not being compatible with a 64 bit OS.

Comment: Ok.Thanks. I installed 32 bit corelab component.

Comment: But i am not able intsall Oracle client  64 bit component on  64 OS . Any idea? Thanks in advance

Comment: What Oracle client are you using?

Comment: 11g 32 bit installed.. trying install 11 g 64 bit.. but got failed

Comment: This is a programming related Q&A site. If you have trouble installing software and configuring your web server it might be better to ask this question on http://serverfault.com where you might get better help. Of course if you only say *but got failed* without actually explaining what exactly have you tried (which exact package have you tried to install with providing a link) and saying the exact error message you got it is unlikely you will get any help.